# android string picker display upper and lower value like iphone

Tags: android, string, picker

Hello all in one of my application i need to do like number picker.. but i need that in like this [image] but i am not able to display it like that(it is in iphone) i can do it just like [image]
have done this  `_number_picker_from.setDisplayedValues( number_picker_from );`
how can i achive this? 
i am using ***android 4.0***

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below url. you will get desired output.

https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/